# du behaves as if -h was always given

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-coreutils

I noticed a strange behaviour of `du` on my system. It always assumes the -h option is set.
Even if I call `/usr/bin/du` directly. No alias is set. This very much get's in the way if I want to do something like

```
du -s * | sort -g
```

It does not make a difference when I try to set a block size. I always get those 'K', 'M' or 'G' abbreviated numbers.

Is there an undocumented environment setting or configuration file that I might have missed?

du is "du (GNU coreutils) 8.32", the System is "Fedora release 34 (Thirty Four)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I was stupid. I somehow got a file named '-h' in the directory I wanted to search.

Comment: ??? So, the presence of a file, called "-h" caused "du" to act like "du -h"???

Comment: Exactly. 
```du -- *```
does help in this case.

Comment: Not "stupid" at all. These kind of things are what make command line adventures fun!